# How to configure access from clients to Firebird 2.5 in Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firebird

I'd like to access a Firebird DB 2.5 from clients. Firebird is installed in Windows 2008 Server, running and operational. There's no connection problems when trying to do it in the server itself. But I'm not reaching do the same when in clients. I've opened 3050 port in Win 2008 Firewall, but nothing happens. When I test the conection using IBExpert, for example, the following erro message appears:

```
Attempting to connect to:
XX.XXX.XXX.XX:SuperFireBD\SuperFireDB.FDB

Connecting... Failed!
------------------------------------
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements.
I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "SuperFireBD\SuperFireDB.FDB".
Error while trying to open file.
The system cannot find the path specified. .

Attempting to connect to services manager... Passed!

Disconnecting from database... Passed!
```

I'm operating over a domain, and I'm not sure wether I have all the grants of the domain's network firewall. Thus, how can I test the 3050 port without telnet? What would I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me it is connecting, but Firebird cannot open your database file.

1. Try an absolute path like `x.x.x.x:c:\SuperFireDB\SuperFireDB.FDB`
2. If that works, I highly suggest making use of aliases.conf located in the Firebird install directory.  Then, clients only have to connect to `x.x.x.x:SuperFireDB` or whatever you decide to name it. If you need to move the database file later, you only have to update aliases.conf and not every client.

Hope this helps!  Also if you install firebird server on your machine (no need to run it), you can try to connect through Firebird's own command line client (ISQL).

Some help here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg10-connecting.html.

Comment: Ok! the problem was on connection string. I followed your suggestion, connecting throught alias.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem.

Answer is very simple: `fbserver.exe` process has no permissions to read/write file `*.fdb`.

I added read/write permissions for the user `SYSTEM` on file `*.fdb` (`fbserver.exe` runs as windows service as user `SYSTEM`) and problems disappear.